# Different array structures and breaking of foreach

Tags: php, arrays, types, difference

I generate XML file from dynamic content but I get 2 array types to get images:
First array type is when there are more than 1 images, example:

```
array(1) {
  ["Images"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Url"]=>
      string(57) "http://example.net/image1.jpg"
      ["Default"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Url"]=>
      string(57) "http://example.net/image2.jpg"
      ["Default"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Url"]=>
      string(57) "http://example.net/image3.jpg"
      ["Default"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Second type is when I had only 1 image, example:

```
array(1) {
  ["Images"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Url"]=>
    string(57) "http://example.net/image111.jpg"
    ["Default"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

How I can make second type to use type of first array, because when I looping these arrays with foreach there is a problem with content. Is there any function to fix this or something?!

**Edit:**
This is the foreach now and it works:

```
$productImages = $product->appendChild($this->_xmlDoc->createElement('ProductImages'));
if(isset($productInfo['ProductImages'])) {
    foreach($productInfo['ProductImages']['Images'] as $image) {
        if(!is_array($image) && is_string($image)) {
            $productImage = $productImages->appendChild($this->_xmlDoc->createElement('ProductImage'));
            $productImage->appendChild($this->_xmlDoc->createElement('ImagePath', $image));
        }
        if(isset($image['Url']) && is_array($image)) {
            $productImage = $productImages->appendChild($this->_xmlDoc->createElement('ProductImage'));
            $productImage->appendChild($this->_xmlDoc->createElement('ImagePath', $image['Url']));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how foreach looks 20 minutes after my question. So I'll vote for first answer, because its similar to my work around :)

Cheers,
Georgi!

Comment: Show us your code (with foreach, etc.)

Comment: your wording is vague, you want to merge second array images with the first array images?

Comment: When you are saying `I generate` and `there is a problem with content`, we expect to see at least: **how** are you generating the stuff and *what kind of problem* do you have. Please add more details about your problem and ways you have tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue before with using a SOAP call. You don't need to change the structure of the array. You can simply change the behaviour of your foreach loop instead, using `is_array`. It checks if the variable is an array or not. Example, using your arrays:

```
$first_array = array(
    "Images" => array(
        array("Url" => "http://example.net/image1.jpg", "Default" => true),
        array("Url" => "http://example.net/image2.jpg", "Default" => false),
        array("Url" => "http://example.net/image3.jpg", "Default" => false)
    )
);

$second_array = array(
    "Images" => array(
        "Url" => "http://example.net/image111.jpg",
        "Default" => true
    )
);

echo "Results on the first array:<br />";

foreach ($first_array["Images"] as $element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        foreach ($element as $value) {
            echo $value . "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo $element . "<br />";
    }
}

echo "<br />";
echo "Result on the second array:<br />";

foreach ($second_array["Images"] as $element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        foreach ($element as $value) {
            echo $value . "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo $element . "<br />";
    }
}
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4y8j-4jd1

Comment: Hi, I made something like this, you can see it in edit of my question :) And my problem is with SOAP API too :P